# Change location of ripple in library android-ripple-background

Tags: java, android, xml, ripple

I've just been getting into using Android libraries and I've been stumbling over this issue for the last few hours. All help is appreciated.

My issue has nothing to do with errors in programming, but more with the behavior of the library. All ripples, by default, appear from the center of the view they're placed in, no matter how much I change the XML layout or code. I'm trying to get the ripples to appear from the top left of the screen, and I'm not entirely sure how to do this... Any ideas? I've already tried placing the content into a ConstraintLayout and then placing the ConstraintLayout partially off screen -- all this did was create a blank white screen. I feel completely out of luck.

Documentation on the library can be found [here](https://github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background).

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: any screen or something concrete ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by this?

Comment: an example of what you tried, a scheme of what you want etc etc

Comment: @jared did you try my posted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Just replace `RippleBackground` library class with below class.***

```
public class RippleBackground extends RelativeLayout{

private static final int DEFAULT_RIPPLE_COUNT=6;
private static final int DEFAULT_DURATION_TIME=3000;
private static final float DEFAULT_SCALE=6.0f;
private static final int DEFAULT_FILL_TYPE=0;

private int rippleColor;
private float rippleStrokeWidth;
private float rippleRadius;
private int rippleDurationTime;
private int rippleAmount;
private int rippleDelay;
private float rippleScale;
private int rippleType;
private Paint paint;
private boolean animationRunning=false;
private AnimatorSet animatorSet;
private ArrayList<Animator> animatorList;
private LayoutParams rippleParams;
private ArrayList<RippleView> rippleViewList=new ArrayList<RippleView>();

public RippleBackground(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public RippleBackground(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public RippleBackground(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (isInEditMode())
        return;

    if (null == attrs) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Attributes should be provided to this view,");
    }

    final TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RippleBackground);
    rippleColor=typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.RippleBackground_rb_color, getResources().getColor(R.color.rippelColor));
    rippleStrokeWidth=typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.RippleBackground_rb_strokeWidth, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.rippleStrokeWidth));
    rippleRadius=typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.RippleBackground_rb_radius,getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.rippleRadius));
    rippleDurationTime=typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.RippleBackground_rb_duration,DEFAULT_DURATION_TIME);
    rippleAmount=typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.RippleBackground_rb_rippleAmount,DEFAULT_RIPPLE_COUNT);
    rippleScale=typedArray.getFloat(R.styleable.RippleBackground_rb_scale,DEFAULT_SCALE);
    rippleType=typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.RippleBackground_rb_type,DEFAULT_FILL_TYPE);
    typedArray.recycle();

    rippleDelay=rippleDurationTime/rippleAmount;

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    if(rippleType==DEFAULT_FILL_TYPE){
        rippleStrokeWidth=0;
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }else
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(rippleColor);

    rippleParams=new LayoutParams((int)(2*(rippleRadius+rippleStrokeWidth)),(int)(2*(rippleRadius+rippleStrokeWidth)));
    //rippleParams.addRule(CENTER_IN_PARENT, TRUE);

    animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    animatorSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animatorList=new ArrayList<Animator>();

    for(int i=0;i<rippleAmount;i++){
        RippleView rippleView=new RippleView(getContext());
        addView(rippleView,rippleParams);
        rippleViewList.add(rippleView);
         final ObjectAnimator scaleXAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rippleView, "ScaleX", 1.0f, rippleScale);
        scaleXAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
        scaleXAnimator.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
        scaleXAnimator.setStartDelay(i * rippleDelay);
        scaleXAnimator.setDuration(rippleDurationTime);
        animatorList.add(scaleXAnimator);
        final ObjectAnimator scaleYAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rippleView, "ScaleY", 1.0f, rippleScale);
        scaleYAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
        scaleYAnimator.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
        scaleYAnimator.setStartDelay(i * rippleDelay);
        scaleYAnimator.setDuration(rippleDurationTime);
        animatorList.add(scaleYAnimator);
        final ObjectAnimator alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rippleView, "Alpha", 1.0f, 0f);
        alphaAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
        alphaAnimator.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
        alphaAnimator.setStartDelay(i * rippleDelay);
        alphaAnimator.setDuration(rippleDurationTime);
        animatorList.add(alphaAnimator);
    }

    animatorSet.playTogether(animatorList);
}

private class RippleView extends View{

    public RippleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int radius=(Math.min(getWidth(),getHeight()))/2;
        canvas.drawCircle(radius,radius,radius-rippleStrokeWidth,paint);
    }
}

public void startRippleAnimation(){
    if(!isRippleAnimationRunning()){
        for(RippleView rippleView:rippleViewList){
            rippleView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        animatorSet.start();
        animationRunning=true;
    }
}

public void stopRippleAnimation(){
    if(isRippleAnimationRunning()){
        animatorSet.end();
        animationRunning=false;
    }
}

public boolean isRippleAnimationRunning(){
    return animationRunning;
}
}
```

> I have tested and working fine with efforts. 
>   PS. if you're using library as dependency then you need to copy library content to your app to make changes.